# CSS float, shift, clear

Tags: css, css-float

I want to float my items list and create a shifted effect from the second item.

How to avoid the "clear" behavior after the second .item?

```css
.shift {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="shift"></div>    

    <div class="item"></div>    
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>    

</div>
```

Here the very simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E477c/).

Is it possible to do it only with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the jQuery plugin [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). You will not get the desired effect with pure css (afaik).

you just should do

```
$('#masonry-container').masonry();
```

I am working on a fiddle for you to show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle example I found: http://jsfiddle.net/m3b6k/1/ (not made by myslef)

```
div.box {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px black inset;
height: 100px;
float: left;
 width: 100px;
background-color: #0f0;
}

.unique {
background-color: #00f !important;
height: 200px !important;
color: #fff;
}
```

if your boxes are static (so a set height) you can use this method. if the size of the boxes is dymanic to its content the only way to solve your problem is using a plugin like http://masonry.desandro.com/